# Why Request::all() returns empty array in __construct of my class which extends FormRequest?

Tags: laravel

```
class MyFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
      
       here Request::all() returns empty array
    }

protected function prepareForValidation()
    {

here Request::all() returns array with my input
```

I need to get input in __construct. Google did not help me.

Pls, help me. How can I get input in __construct()?

I use Laravel 7.

Comment: the form request is actually filled (initialized) after it is created when resolved from the container

Comment: I understand it. But must be way to get input in constructor. I can use _GET or _POST. But I think it's not a good idea.

Comment: what are you doing in the constructor that you need that data?

Comment: I get Model object (document). Other methods: authorize(), prepareForValidation(), rules() use it. 
I can get object from route. 
```
$this->doc = Route::input('doc');
```

But now I need to get document by input params.

Comment: _POST is empty in __construct() :(

Comment: `prepareForValidation` seems like a good place to be dealing with data before authorization and validation happen

Comment: Yes, but all other methods use the same data. 

I can add my init method and call it from all other methods, however I think it's not right solution. See below solution with __construct(). 

__construct() is a right place to init all data. Other methods process data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

Or have you tried the helper function `request()->all()`

I have tried both in a construct method of my controllers and works fine